What caused this user's burst of Announcer/Booster/Publicist awarded badges?
I stumbled across this user's profile as I remembered that user's long track of their propagandist activity on whitewashing war crimes.
The user seems to have been suspended back in 2023 (no post activity since that time).
However, that user's profile is full of awarded promotion badges (up to the gold badge of "Publicist"). There are literally eight pages of badge awards there, dated long after the (assumed) user's suspension.

My questions are:

What may have caused such burst of link promotion?
Is there any irregularity here?
Did the Moderators have chance to check whether the mentioned user is a part of a bigger network of sockpuppet accounts who promote each other, like it happens on most social networks in the recent time?

Additionally (may be somewhat subjective): what could be the reason for a currently suspended user to share links referencing to their profile that (hopefully) will not be unsuspended in the nearest 175 years (2298)?

I find the "Favorite Answer" -- "Answer saved by 25 users" the most suspicious. No other user on the whole site seems to have that one. https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/184/favorite-answer And that user has two of those, awarded quasi-simultaneously on Mar 22.

One of the answers so saved has +2/-3 score, so who'd have found that one worth saving is hard to say...

And the publicist badge has all of its site instances (to date 11) award to this one user https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist And 9 of those 11 were awarded in the span of two days (Jan 5-6). I'm guessing the 100+ years suspension is (already) for sockpuppets or similar.

A ban till 2298, that's quite aggressive.  Don't want them to sneak back in @ 120.

@264champagnebottlesonice I doubt anyone would suspend someone for gaming Publicist. Frankly, it causes no harm actual harm to the site doing that. Same thing for favorite answer.

Every share link has the users profile id in the link. It is very likely that they have just been sharing those links in other places and haven't bothered to remove their id from those links. As an example if I go to share this question it has my id in the link
https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994/20715

In this case 6994 is the id of the question and 20715 is my user id on this site.
Here is what the restrictions are on the user who is suspended
A Day in the Penalty Box

Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.

The only restrictions are on voting, asking questions, answering questions and leaving comments. I assume chat is also included but not listed here.
The user is still able to access the site and features such as favoriting questions and answers or sharing posts.

This seems to address the last (subjective) part, thanks. It does not, however, seem to address the main question (possible bot network). Old posts in social networks get covered with newer ones and never last for years. Go try finding someone's 2-years-old post on FB or Twitter, for instance. One has to actively bump them. Or to do so with some kind of automation/sockpuppetry. Hence the question.

@BeBraveBeLikeUkraine Why do you think that the user in question can't be still posting share links even if they currently have a network wide suspension? You don't know where they are sharing the links and just because it is an old question here doesn't mean it wasn't a recent share for them.

If the "publicist" badge didn't require accounts, the  "Favorite Answer" one surely does though.

@IVFcomesfromthetip A suspension doesn't remove the account or prevent users from accessing it, rather it just limits what things they can do such as voting, posting questions/answers, commenting, chat, and a few other things. From what I understand they can still login and do things such as share questions and favorite questions/answers.
